# How to properly satisfy trait bounds in Rust while using ndarray structs

Tags: generics, rust, traits, rust-ndarray

I am trying to implement a Tensor struct that will hold an Array from ndarray crate, where `T` is the element type, and `I` for the dimensionality. The core idea of the struct is to hold a two dimensional or a three dimensional array.

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use ndarray::ArrayBase;
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use ndarray::OwnedRepr;
use ndarray::{Array};
use ndarray::Array3;
use ndarray::Dimension;

struct Tensor<T,I> 
where T: Clone + Sync + Send,
I: PartialEq + Debug 
{
   data: ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>,Dim<I>>
}


impl<T,I> Tensor<T,I>
where T: Clone + Sync + Send,
I: PartialEq + Debug 
{    
     pub fn new(arr:ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>,Dim<I>>) -> Self {
       Self {data: arr }
     }

     pub fn shape(&self) -> &[usize] {
       self.data.shape()
     }
}


fn main() {
    let mut temperature = Array3::<f32>::zeros((3, 4, 5));
    let shape = temperature.shape();
    let t3D:Tensor<f32,[usize;3]> = Tensor::new(temperature);
}
```

I wanted to create a `shape()` method, associated to the `Tensor` struct, that returns the shape of the ndarray residing in the `data` field.

But `rustc` throws an error saying that:

```
error[E0599]: the method `shape` exists for struct `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<I>>`, but its
trait bounds were not satisfied

**error[E0599]: the method `shape` exists for struct `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<I>>`, 
but its     trait bounds were not satisfied
--> src/main.rs:36:20
   |
36 |          self.data.shape()
   |                    ^^^^^ method cannot be called on `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<I>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds**


doesn't satisfy `<_ as DimAdd<Dim<IxDynImpl>>>::Output = Dim<IxDynImpl>`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as DimAdd<Dim<[usize; 0]>>>::Output = Dim<I>`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as DimAdd<Dim<[usize; 1]>>>::Output = <Dim<I> as Dimension>::Larger`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as DimMax<<Dim<I> as Dimension>::Larger>>::Output = <Dim<I> as Dimension>::Larger`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as DimMax<<Dim<I> as Dimension>::Smaller>>::Output = Dim<I>`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as DimMax<Dim<I>>>::Output = Dim<I>`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as DimMax<Dim<IxDynImpl>>>::Output = Dim<IxDynImpl>`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as DimMax<Dim<[usize; 0]>>>::Output = Dim<I>`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as Index<usize>>::Output = usize`
| doesn't satisfy `<_ as Mul<usize>>::Output = Dim<I>`
| doesn't satisfy `<ndarray::Dim<I> as Add>::Output = ndarray::Dim<I>`
| doesn't satisfy `<ndarray::Dim<I> as Mul>::Output = ndarray::Dim<I>`
| doesn't satisfy `<ndarray::Dim<I> as Sub>::Output = ndarray::Dim<I>`
| doesn't satisfy `_: DimAdd<<Dim<I> as Dimension>::Larger>`
| doesn't satisfy `_: DimAdd<<Dim<I> as Dimension>::Smaller>`
| doesn't satisfy `_: DimMax<<Dim<I> as Dimension>::Larger>`
| doesn't satisfy `_: DimMax<<Dim<I> as Dimension>::Smaller>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: AddAssign<&'x ndarray::Dim<I>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: AddAssign`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Add`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Clone`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Default`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: DimAdd<ndarray::Dim<I>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: DimAdd<ndarray::Dim<IxDynImpl>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: DimAdd<ndarray::Dim<[usize; 0]>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: DimAdd<ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: DimMax<ndarray::Dim<I>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: DimMax<ndarray::Dim<IxDynImpl>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: DimMax<ndarray::Dim<[usize; 0]>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Dimension`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Eq`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: IndexMut<usize>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Mul<usize>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: MulAssign<&'x ndarray::Dim<I>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: MulAssign<usize>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: MulAssign`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Mul`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Send`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: SubAssign<&'x ndarray::Dim<I>>`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: SubAssign`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Sub`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: Sync`
| doesn't satisfy `ndarray::Dim<I>: std::ops::Index<usize>`
```

I tried to apply trait bounds to the `struct` and also the `impl` but the compiler keeps throwing the error

So I have a couple of questions:

1. How to add the trait bounds properly to the above code?
2. How to Identify the trait bound a particular method needs?

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain `where Dim<I>: Dimension`.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to simply add a bound of `Dim<I>: Dimension` on your `impl` block (note BTW that you can remove the bounds on the `struct` itself):

```
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use ndarray::Array;
use ndarray::Array3;
use ndarray::ArrayBase;
use ndarray::Dimension;
use ndarray::OwnedRepr;
use std::fmt::Debug;

struct Tensor<T, I> {
    data: ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<I>>,
}

impl<T, I> Tensor<T, I>
where
    T: Clone + Sync + Send,
    I: PartialEq + Debug,
    Dim<I>: Dimension,
{
    pub fn new(arr: ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<I>>) -> Self {
        Self { data: arr }
    }

    pub fn shape(&self) -> &[usize] {
        self.data.shape()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut temperature = Array3::<f32>::zeros((3, 4, 5));
    let shape = temperature.shape();
    let t3D: Tensor<f32, [usize; 3]> = Tensor::new(temperature);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=05e10c65de1952b1d72decd875b17005)

This can be deduced from the docs because the [`impl ArrayBase` block that defines the `shape` method](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-ArrayBase%3CS%2C%20D%3E-2) is:

```
impl<A, S, D> ArrayBase<S, D> where
    S: RawData<Elem = A>,
    D: Dimension,
```

In your case `D` is `Dim<I>`, so you want `Dim<I>: Dimension`.